# Duda con operador ternario

Tags: php

Tengo dudas como interpretar esto:

```
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
```

¿Quiere decir que si page no esta declarado y no esta vacio va a recoger el valor de page y de lo contrario $page tomará el valor "1"?

Comment: Todo lo anterior al ? es la condición la cual comprueba que $_REQUEST['page'] esta definido y no esta vacio, después del ? va el retorno si el resultado de la condición es true, asignando en este caso el valor de $_REQUEST['page'], en caso contrario (que no se cumpla la condición) se asigna 1. Sería similar a 

`if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])) {
 $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
 $page = 1;
}`

Comment: Si, es tal cual dices. Pimero se pone el if, después el separador " ? " que separa el if de las respuestas. Y finalmente las respuestas separadas por " : ".

Answer (score 7):

Un operador ternario es una condición que te devuelve un resultado.

La condición se escribe primero, antes de la interrogación, y el resultado devuelto detrás de ella. Si la condición se cumple retorna un valor, que es el que está a la izquierda de los dos puntos, si no se cumple retorna el valor de la derecha.

Sería algo así:

```
$valor = condición ? $seCumple : $noSeCumple;
```

En tu caso quiere decir que si existe y no está vacío `$_REQUEST['page']` se devuelve su valor, si no existe le devuelve 1

En php 7 esta funcion fue mejorada con el operador ternario null (??)
que ayuda a evitar el uso de isset devolviendo el primer valor no null.
tu ejemplo pasaria de esto:

```
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
```

a esto:

```
$page = $_REQUEST['page'] ?? 1;
```